# Is there a one-click shortcut for executing all jupyter notebooks opened in the browser?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, execution

Is there a one-click shortcut for executing all jupyter notebooks opened in the browser? I do not mean just to execute all the cells in one of the jupyter notebook, but to execute all the cells in all of the jupyter notebooks at the same time. Thank you.

Comment: I do not believe such a shortcut exists. One solution that came to mind was to make a Chrome extension that cycles through all Jupyter notebook tabs and executes the run-all-cells shortcut on each one. However, I am not sure how feasible this is.

Comment: There is no shortcut, but you can execute Jupyter notebooks from the command line: https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html